# RouterLink inside a repeater angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, angular2-routing

There is a `routerLink` that enables the necessary routes for navigation provided with the `config`.

It works fine, if it is done something like below:

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But it fails when used inside a `*ngFor` repeater, like this

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let item of menu">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" [routerLink]="['{{item.link}}']">{{item.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have searched enough on `Google` but I wasn't able to find a satisfying answer.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You don't need `'{{item.link}}'`

Use only `item.link` without `''` and `{{}}`

```html
<ul class="nav">
     <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let item of menu">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#" [routerLink]="[item.link]">{{item.name}}</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to concatenate the `routerLink`

you can do

```
[routerLink]="['./page/' + item.id]"
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm

Comment: @Arun Kumar Don't forget to accept an answer if it works for you. So other folks could easily find it.

Comment: Any chance you could add a why?  You don't need ... because...?

Comment: @ShaneCourtrille Because Angular already evaluates the contents of angular tag properties.   {{ }} is for use outside of angular properties, like between tags.  If it's not a standard html element property, but instead one added as part of angular, then you're already golden.